# Nuxt ssr application render time test

Tags: testing, nuxt.js, render

I have a nuxt ssr application. I want to test render time of application. Are there any methods or tools for test that?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, can you give us more details please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lighthouse](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lighthouse/blipmdconlkpinefehnmjammfjpmpbjk?hl=en) on chrome, there is also a Firefox version too. First make sure you run the the app in build mode(npn run build > npm run start). Testing it in development mode will take too long and results will probably be inaccurate.

Go to the lighthouse tab in the inspect tool and click "generate report". It will produce a report like in the below picture. Click the "View Original Trace" button. [image]

There you can see the render time and other benchmark results in detail.
[image]